# Astar optimalization (A*)

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx, path-finding

So I have written own implementation of AStar (A*) algorithm to find paths around my 2d tile based map. My problem is that if I call it each frame (I need to do it) and I'm searching path from corner of map to corner, my game runs at c.a. 7 fps. How can I can optimize it here is the code:

```
package com.kubasienki.survive.pathfinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import com.kubasienki.survive.cave.Dungeon;
import com.kubasienki.survive.cave.Map;

public class PathFinder {

    public ArrayList<Node> open = new ArrayList<Node>();
    public ArrayList<Node> closed = new ArrayList<Node>();
    ArrayList<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public void print(ArrayList<Node> array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("S " + array.get(i).x + "\t" + array.get(i).y
                    + "\t" + i + "\\" + array.size());
        }
    }

    public int findNode(Node node, ArrayList<Node> array) {
        // //////System.out.println("####################"+array.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            // //////System.out.println("S " + array.get(i).x + "\t" +
            // array.get(i).y
            // + "\t" + i);
            if (node.x == array.get(i).x && node.y == array.get(i).y) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    void chceckNeighbour(Node nodee, Dungeon map, int endX, int endY) {

        // ////System.out.println("CHECKED: " + nodee.x + "\t" + nodee.y +
        // " closed: "
        // + findNode(nodee, closed) + " open: " + findNode(nodee, open));
        // print(open);
        int iterator = findNode(nodee, closed);
        if (!closed.isEmpty() && iterator != -1
                && nodee.cost < closed.get(iterator).cost) {
            // ////System.out.println("FOUND IN CLOSED");
            closed.get(iterator).parentX = nodee.x;
            closed.get(iterator).parentY = nodee.y;
            closed.get(iterator).cost = nodee.cost;
            closed.get(iterator).costH = nodee.cost + Math.abs(nodee.x - endX)
                    + Math.abs(nodee.y - endY);
        }
        iterator = findNode(nodee, open);
        if (!open.isEmpty() && iterator != -1
                && nodee.cost < open.get(iterator).cost) {
            // ////System.out.println("FOUND IN OPEN");
            open.get(iterator).parentX = nodee.x;
            open.get(iterator).parentY = nodee.y;
            open.get(iterator).cost = nodee.cost;
            open.get(iterator).costH = nodee.cost + Math.abs(nodee.x - endX)
                    + Math.abs(nodee.y - endY);
        } else if (findNode(nodee, open) == -1 && findNode(nodee, closed) == -1) {
            // ////System.out.println("ADDING NEW: " + nodee.x + "\t" +
            // nodee.y);
            open.add(new Node());
            open.get(open.size() - 1).cost = nodee.cost;
            open.get(open.size() - 1).costH = nodee.costH;
            open.get(open.size() - 1).x = nodee.x;
            open.get(open.size() - 1).y = nodee.y;
            open.get(open.size() - 1).parentX = nodee.parentX;
            open.get(open.size() - 1).parentY = nodee.parentY;

            // //////System.out.print("''''''''''''''''''''" + findNode(nodee,
            // open));

            /*
             * for(Node nodez : open){
             * //////System.out.print(nodez.x+"\t"+nodez.y+"|"); }
             */
        }
    }

    public void checkNeighbours(Node node, Dungeon map, int endX, int endY) {
        Node gen = new Node();
        // print(open);
        if (node.x != 0) {
            gen.x = (node.x - 1);
            gen.y = node.y;
            if (Dungeon.dungeon.get(gen.x).get(gen.y)) {
                gen.cost = node.cost + 500;
            } else {
                gen.cost = node.cost + 1;
            }
            gen.costH = node.cost + Math.abs(gen.x - endX)
                    + Math.abs(gen.y - endY);
            gen.parentX = node.x;
            gen.parentY = node.y;
            // ////System.out.println("x-1");
            chceckNeighbour(gen, map, endX, endY);
        }
        if (node.y != 0) {
            gen.x = node.x;
            gen.y = (node.y - 1);
            if (Dungeon.dungeon.get(gen.x).get(gen.y)) {
                gen.cost = node.cost + 500;
            } else {
                gen.cost = node.cost + 1;
            }
            gen.costH = gen.cost + Math.abs(gen.x - endX)
                    + Math.abs(gen.y - endY);
            gen.parentX = node.x;
            gen.parentY = node.y;
            // ////System.out.println("y-1");
            chceckNeighbour(gen, map, endX, endY);
        }
        if (node.x < Dungeon.dungeon.size() - 1) {
            gen.x = (node.x + 1);
            gen.y = node.y;
            if (Dungeon.dungeon.get(gen.x).get(gen.y)) {
                gen.cost = node.cost + 500;
            } else {
                gen.cost = node.cost + 1;
            }
            gen.costH = gen.cost + Math.abs(gen.x - endX)
                    + Math.abs(gen.y - endY);
            gen.parentX = node.x;
            gen.parentY = node.y;
            // ////System.out.println("x+1");
            chceckNeighbour(gen, map, endX, endY);
        }
        if (node.y < Dungeon.dungeon.get(0).size() - 1) {
            gen.x = node.x;
            gen.y = (node.y + 1);
            if (Dungeon.dungeon.get(gen.x).get(gen.y)) {
                gen.cost = node.cost + 500;
            } else {
                gen.cost = node.cost + 1;
            }
            gen.costH = gen.cost + Math.abs(gen.x - endX)
                    + Math.abs(gen.y - endY);
            gen.parentX = node.x;
            gen.parentY = node.y;
            // ////System.out.println("y+1");
            chceckNeighbour(gen, map, endX, endY);
            // //////System.out.println("REMOVE");
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> find(Dungeon map, int startX, int startY, int endX,
            int endY) {
        // ////System.out.println("SEARCHING START");

        boolean goal = false;
        open.clear();
        closed.clear();
        path.clear();
        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.x = startX;
        temp.y = startY;
        temp.cost = 0;
        temp.costH = Math.abs(startX - endX) + Math.abs(startY - endY);
        temp.parentX = -1;
        temp.parentY = -1;
        open.add(temp);
        // print(open);

        while (!goal) {

            // //////System.out.println(closed.size());

            // SORTING
            // //////System.out.println(open.size());
            // print(open);
            // //////System.out.println();
            Collections.sort(open, new Comparator<Node>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                    return o1.costH - o2.costH;

                }
            });
            // /SORTING END
            // for(Node nodez : open){
            // //////System.out.print(nodez.x+"\t"+nodez.y+"|");
            // }
            if (open.isEmpty()) {
                // //////System.out.println("EMPTY");
            } else {

                if (open.get(0).x == endX && open.get(0).y == endY) {
                    goal = true;
                } else {
                    // ////System.out.println("#################" +
                    // open.get(0).x
                    // + "\t" + open.get(0).y + "#################");
                    closed.add(open.get(0));
                    temp = open.get(0);
                    open.remove(0);
                    // //////System.out.println("REMOVE:\t" + temp.x + "\t" +
                    // temp.y);
                    // //////System.out.println(temp.x + "\t" + temp.y + "\t" +
                    // (temp.cost));
                    checkNeighbours(temp, map, endX, endY);

                }
            }

        }
        // ////System.out.println("SEARCHING END");
        boolean start = false;
        Node back = new Node();
        back = open.get(0);

        while (!start) {
            // System.out.println("x: " + back.x + " y: " + back.y + "");
            path.add(new Node());
            // System.out.println("NEW PATH PART");
            path.get(path.size() - 1).x = back.x;
            path.get(path.size() - 1).y = back.y;
            // System.out.println("x: " + path.get(path.size()-1).x + " y: " +
            // path.get(path.size()-1).y + "");
            back.x = back.parentX;
            back.y = back.parentY;
            back = closed.get(findNode(back, closed));
            int i = findNode(back, closed);
            if (closed.get(i).parentX == -1) {
                start = true;
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("RETURNING PATH");
        // print(path);
        return path;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pick *part* of it you want to optimize and ask about that. There's no correct answer to how to optimize all that code. Profile it to find out which parts are slowest, then you can make informed decisions about where to focus your efforts.

Comment: Hi. You said you have a tile based game. Normally in such a game, all paths could be detected in advance. If knowing all paths in advance n^2 is too much, it is often possible to create a divides model of the space in a type of navmesh or bsp and remember paths to larger areas. Recalculating the path each frame is possibly very bad. Another solution would be to divide the path finding algorithm into chunks, run a small chunk each frame and complete one run approximately once per second (or half second). Doing only 1/30 of the work each frame.

Comment: @Artur Wulf White I was thinking about dividing my map into sectors and adding precalculated waypoints to them. But my map i generated in fly.

Comment: You have to minimize the loops within your pathfinding loop. Looking up your close and open list several times each time is causing lag. Make your closed list a normal array [,] and just look up x, y fromyour current position. You can do the same on open list some times. In my a star code i only loop the open list a single time, when looking for the lowest f score. It takes about 250ms to travel a 256x256 map from corner to corner on a harsh map. About 25ms on a open map. Are you completely sure you have to find a path each seccond?

Comment: IMHO this is a good question. Obviously, the task is to optimize "all that code", no matter what the closing squad says. You could use profiling to find the critical part, however, looking at the whole makes more sense. Some tips: 1. On a small device not everything gets optimized as well as in a server VM, so using local variables for things like `open.size() - 1` may help. 2. In case your lists get large, using a `HashMap` can speed up `findNode` a lot. 3. As you move through the dungeon, the optimal path changes slowly and you might be able to reuse some old value.

Comment: 4. Try your luck on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+optimization), as your problem is more a general code optimization than game specific.